# Dimensions and Basis of fields short questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I have some short examples but don't exactly know how they work.

> ex1. dim $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$
>
> ex2. dim $\mathbb{R}(\sqrt2)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$
>
> ex3. Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) $ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1,
>  2^{1/3}, 2^{2/3}$.
>
> ex4. Basis of $F(\sqrt3)$ over $F$ is $1, 3^{1/2}$
>
> ex5. Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)(\sqrt3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1,
> 2^{1/3}, 2^{2/3}, \sqrt3, \sqrt3 *2^{1/3}, \sqrt3*2^{2/3}$.  So it's
> $6$ dimensional vector space.

This is my first time studying "Extending Fields" but the solutions are too short for me to understand.

**EX1**. I think $i$ is the solution to $x^2+1$. Is that why dimension is $2$?

**EX2**. If I were to do the same thing as in **EX1**, $x^2-1$ has $\sqrt2$ as a root. Then shouldn't the dimension be $2$?

**EX3**. The polynomial that has $\sqrt[3]2$ as a solution is $x^3 - 2$. And then what do I do?

**EX4**. Same as **EX3**. Found the polynomial $x^2 -3$. Can't figure out the next step.

**EX5**. No idea for this one..

Comment: Ex 1: A **basis** of $\Bbb C\mid \Bbb R$ is $\{1,i\}$. So the vetcor space dimension (which *is* just the degree $[\Bbb C:\Bbb R]$ is $2$, the cardinality of a basis. Ex2: Since $\sqrt{2}\in \Bbb R$ we have $\Bbb R(\sqrt{2})=\Bbb R$. So the basis is $\{1\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok thx! but why is basis $\{1,i\}$? I still don't get how to find basis.

Comment: Every complex number $z$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $i$, i.e., $z=a\cdot 1+b\cdot i$ for $a,b\in \Bbb R$, don't you know this? Of course, $1$ and $i$ are linearly independent over $ \Bbb R$ (linear algebra!).

Comment: @DietrichBurde oh I do I do. Then in ex1, why do I need "over $\mathbb{R}$"? Can't I just say the basis of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\{1,i\}$?

Comment: $\{1,i\}$ is not a basis of $\Bbb C$, say, over $\Bbb Q$ - why not?? So what you need, is to review vector spaces. Any field extension $L\mid K$ makes $L$ a $K$-vector space. The cardinality of a basis is the field extension degree. What is the degree of $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ over $\Bbb Q$, for example?

Comment: @DietrichBurde isn't it $1$?

Comment: No, it isn't. OK, I have to leave. So first review vector spaces, then post questions on field extensions :)